# Slick2d locating an x and y through pixel colour

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception, slick2d

I am trying to make holdable items for my `slick2d` game, I figured a good way to do this would be to have a hand on the player, to do this i have 1 pixel a unique colour, allowing me to locate that colour, and the `x +y`.

It worked perfectly until i tried to scale up the image and i get this crazy out of bounds exeception.

this is my code to find the `x` and `y`:

```
    public int[] getLocation(Image i, Color c){
    Image scaled = i.getScaledCopy(getWidth(), getHeight());
    for(int x = 0; x < scaled.getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < scaled.getHeight(); y++){
            if(scaled.getColor(x, y).r == c.r && scaled.getColor(x, y).g == c.g && scaled.getColor(x, y).b == c.b){
                int[] xy = {x,y};
                return xy;

            }
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is how i use it

```
    float x = (float) (getLocation(walkLeft.getCurrentFrame(), new Color(1, 1, 1))[0] + getX());
    float y = (float) (getLocation(walkLeft.getCurrentFrame(), new Color(1, 1, 1))[1] + getY());
    g.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
```

the exception is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16384
```

and it leads me back to this line:

```
                if(i.getColor(x, y).r == c.r && i.getColor(x, y).g == c.g && i.getColor(x, y).b == c.b){
```

in the `getLocation` method..
I have a feeling its dead easy, yet its stumped me. Thanks to anyone to responds.

Comment: Why scale the Image? The `getLocation` loops over the width/height of a 2x scaled copy of the Image, then attempts to check the pixels of the original

Comment: I updated the getLocation, still getting the same problem

Comment: `I updated the getLocation` The update uses getWidth() and getHeight() - which may again differ in size from original Image (unclear from posted code). Why do you need to scale?

Comment: My game art is in a very pixelated style, i achieve this by creating a smaller image and enlarging it to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

The loop(s) in `getLocation` loop over the dimensions of a 2x scaled copy of the Image, but then attempt to access the pixels of the original. Given the original is half the size, when you are half-way through the loop you will be out of bounds of the image dimensions. Either:

1. Don't scale the Image
2. If you must scale the Image, check the pixel value of the scaled image rather than the original.

As an aside, the code posted contains redundant calls...a) in `getLocation` if you are going to scale, consider scaling the image once rather than placing that code within the loop itself b) no need to call `getLocation` twice with the same parameters. Call it once and just use the returned array

Comment: I updated the getLocation method, to check the scaled version, same problem.

Comment: I have found a temporary solution to this problem, yet it is still bugging me. I times the x by the scaled amount of the image, it appears to work yet i am still looking for solutions as to why my previous code did not work